# Source Server and Symbol Server Azure Dev-Ops

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Azure Dev Ops to run a test on being able to debug a .dll I don't have the source code locally.  However, I have run into a problem.

I have a C# .net Standard library with a single class containing a single method in it.  I'm using Azure DevOps to do the build for this library.  I have created the build pipeline template for an ASP.NET project.  The YAML for my build pipeline is as follows:

steps:

```
task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
inputs:
  versionSpec: 4.4.1

task: NuGetCommand@2
displayName: 'NuGet restore'
inputs:
  restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
  vstsFeed: 'a1deac36-75b8-4a5c-a86c-26a137db5913'

task: VSBuild@1
displayName: 'Build solution'
inputs:
  solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
  msbuildArgs: '/t:restore;build;pack /p:PackageVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber) /p:PackageOutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) /p:AssemblyFileVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  clean: true
  msbuildArchitecture: x64

task: PublishSymbols@2
displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
inputs:
  SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
  SymbolServerType: TeamServices
continueOnError: true

task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
inputs:
  PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
```

The build creates .dll, .pdb, and .nupkg files.  The .pdb appears to be uploaded correctly to the Symbol Server I have access to.  I have created a local c# console app project referencing the built .nupkg file.   When I run the console app, it says it loaded symbols successfully from the Symbol Server (my Symbol Cache locally has the corresponding .pdb file).  However, when I go to step into the method contained in the class in the .dll, I am prompted for the source code file.  In my output window in Visual Studio there is the following error:

```
SRCSRV: The module 'C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\Source\Workspaces\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll' does not contain source server information.
```

I have the 'Enable source server support' checkbox checked, along with the top two child checkboxes selected.  I also have 'Enable Just My Code' unchecked and 'Enable Source Link support' checked.

I have read over all of the Microsoft docs pages about .pdbs and Azure Dev-Ops and believe I have everything set correctly, but for some reason it still prompts me for the source file instead of being able to use the source server.  So am I missing something in my build or somewhere else that would cause this error when trying to step into the compiled code?

Comment: Are you building in a debug configuration or a release configuration?

Comment: I have tried both, neither have worked.

Comment: Figured out the problem... .NET standard projects by default create portable .pdb files (thus not including source server information).  I had to add the following two properties to the msbuild options: /p:DebugType=full and /p:DebugSymbols=true.  Even though my project was already configured for this, looks like the default build process step in Azure Dev-Ops overrides this setting.